# Python subprocess never exits and keeps giving empty strings in output

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stderr

So, I have been facing a problem with using subprocess for a python app i am writing. To illustrate the problem, I wrote this small script that replicates my problem pretty well.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import subprocess as sp
from select import select

p = sp.Popen(['ls'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE)
p.stdin.close()

while p.returncode is None or p.stdout.closed or p.stderr.closed:
    # print('returncode is', p.returncode)
    available_readers = select([p.stdout, p.stderr], [], [], 2.0)[0]
    for r in available_readers:
        print(r.read(1))
        # output_display.insert(tk.END, r.read(1))
```

Ofcourse, we all know that `ls` command exists immediately after printing some stuff to `stdout` (or may be `stderr`), but the above script never exists.

As you can see from the last line (comment) in the above script, I have to put the content from the subprocess into a tk text component. So, I can't use methods like `.communicate` and other blocking calls as the command I need to run takes a long time and I need to show the output (almost) realtime. (Ofcourse, I have to run this in a separate thread when running Tk, but that's something else).

So, I am unable to understand why this script never exits. It keeps printing empty strings forever (after the expected output of the `ls` command).

Please advise. I am running python 2.6.6 on ubuntu 10.10

Edit: Here's the version of the above script that works

```
from __future__ import print_function

import subprocess as sp
from select import select

p = sp.Popen(['ls'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE)
p.stdin.close()

while p.poll() is None:
    # print('returncode is', p.returncode)
    available_readers = select([p.stdout, p.stderr], [], [], 2.0)[0]
    for r in available_readers:
        print(r.read(1), end='')
        # output_display.insert(tk.END, r.read(1))

print(p.stdout.read(), end='')
print(p.stderr.read(), end='')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while p.returncode is None or p.stdout.closed or p.stderr.closed:
```

loops while *any* of the conditions is true. You probably meant to check just `returncode` (and `poll` in every iteration).